# How to sum pixel values of a floating point raster in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, statistics

I have a floating point raster with values from 60 up to 95 (with decimals), it has 7077 pixels of 250x250m size.

Is there a way to sum all pixel values of this raster? For example, if the raster had 3 pixels with values of 60.20, 71.43 and 86.59, the sum would be 218.22.

I tried with zonal statistics and cell statistics, but it does not work. I am using ArcMap 10.1.

Comment: If you don't mind rounding to an integer you can do that and then just open the VAT (attribute table). If you need more precision, I might try creating a zone that encompasses the full extent and doing a "Zonal Sum" with Spatial Analyst.

Comment: I haven't got ArcGIS to hand right now, but if you right click, select properties, and look under the general or source tab it might have a sum description, let me know if this doesn't help and I will look further.

Comment: I tried that but it only appears the max, min, mean and SD.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a Python `numpy` array and a [.sum()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) operation to sum all of the floating point values in the array. ArcGIS has an easy interface to convert raster data to a numpy array by using [RasterToNumPyArray (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000029000000)

```py
# Import the arcpy site package
import arcpy, numpy

# Your input floating point raster
raster = r'C:\temp\floating_point_raster.tif'

# Convert the raster to a numpy array
array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster, nodata_to_value = 0)

# Sum the array
array.sum()
```

Comment: With the new change it perfectly works! Thank you!

Comment: But I am getting `return _RasterToNumPyArray(*args, **kwargs) MemoryError:` even to 400MB raster.

Answer (score -2):

A simple method is:

mean pixel value * total number of pixels

The source tab in layer properties has all the information you need for this calculation.

Comment: This approach assumes your raster has no nodata values so would vastly over estimate if your raster has many nodata cells. @Aaron has a much more robust solution.